# Error while accessing array of pointers to structures

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I am trying to make an array of structures in which each array elements itself points to another structure of the same type. In order to better explain the problem, I have made a schematic for it! The names of the variables are according to the code (shown below)

But I am getting an error while I am freeing the memory! Can someone provide some hints for solving this! Thanks.

[image: array of structures]

**Error:**

```
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:36:42: error: member reference type 'Vertex *' (aka 'struct Node *') is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?
        Vertex* ptr = (*(vertexarray+ i)).next;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
                                         ->
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:57:14: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'Vertex [4]' to parameter of type 'Vertex **' (aka 'struct Node **') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    finalize(vertexarray);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
tempCodeRunnerFile.c:30:24: note: passing argument to parameter 'vertexarray' here
void finalize(Vertex** vertexarray){ // free the dynamic memmory 
                       ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Data structure to store a linked list node
typedef struct Node
{   int data;
    struct Node* next;
}Vertex;

Vertex* initialize(); //Vertex** vertexarray
void finalize(Vertex** vertexarray);

Vertex* initialize(){ // initialise the elements inside the array
    
    Vertex* node = (Vertex*)malloc(sizeof(Vertex));

    if(node ==NULL){
        printf("Error in initialising"); // If node cannot be created due to memmory issues.
        return NULL; // listhead is NULL
    }
    else{
    node->data = -1; // The initial node is empty (contains data value -1, symbolising empty).
    node->next = NULL; // The list at the time of initialisation is empty and hence no node to further point on.
    }
    return node;

}

void finalize(Vertex** vertexarray){ // free the dynamic memmory 

    int i;

    for (i=0; i<4;i++){ // free all the memmory
        
        Vertex* ptr = (*(vertexarray+ i)).next; 
        Vertex* tmp;

        while( ptr!= NULL) // Termination condition: At the end, the pointer is not pointing to any node, but a NULL value
        {
            tmp = ptr; // make tmp the current node starting from listhead.
            ptr = ptr->next; // update the pointer to the next pointer
            free(tmp); // free the previous pointer
        }   
    }

}

int main(void)
{
    Vertex vertexarray[4];
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<4;i++){
        vertexarray[i].next = initialize();
    }
    finalize(vertexarray);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Either change `*(vertexarray+ i)` to `vertexarray[i]`, or add parenthesis around it, in order to fix the operator precedence issue in your code: `(*(vertexarray+ i)).next`. Nice drawing BTW.

Comment: This appears as if you couldn't decide whether you wanted a dynamic pointer array, a dynamic array, or a fixed array, and ended up trying all three concurrently.

Comment: @WhozCraig Haha, yes! The problem statement was like that! Btw are you talking about the figure or the implementation? Because In the figure I will extend each array element to a dynamic linked list!

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb Sure, thanks for the suggestion! But I think I still need to fix some more things, since the code isn't running yet!

Comment: Well, that's a different issue. You posted a compilation error, so I addressed that.

Comment: @WhozCraig Why is the figure bad? Does it not make sense? Or just the implementation? I can't change the implementation because that't what being asked in the problem statement. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @WhozCraig ; Yeah, I saw that! Thanks again!

Comment: I'm talking about the implementation. That figure is pretty bad, though. It *looks* like they want a fixed value array, which chains from each value. Not what I would do, but apparently what they want. And fwiw, changing `*(vertexarray+ i).next`  to `vertexarray[i].next;` (or `(*(vertexarray+ i)).next`) won't fix anything, including the compilation problem. All those are synonymous with what you started with. There isn't a precedence issue there whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the finalize method would need to free every element of the array you could write it like this

```
void finalize(Vertex vertexarray[], size_t len)
{ // free the dynamic memmory

  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
  { // free all the memmory

    Vertex *ptr = vertexarray[i].next;
    Vertex *tmp;

    while (ptr != NULL) // Termination condition: At the end, the pointer is not pointing to any node, but a NULL value
    {
      tmp = ptr;       // make tmp the current node starting from listhead.
      ptr = ptr->next; // update the pointer to the next pointer
      free(tmp);       // free the previous pointer
    }
  }
}
```

And call it in main as

```
finalize(vertexarray, 4);
```

It will still work if vertexarray will allocated dynamically as you still need to keep track of how many elements has. Unless you change the vertexarray to also be a list

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! Great help! Also, is there any way in which I can implement `void finalize(Vertex** vertexarray)` ? I couldn't really understand how to work with Vertex** vertexarray in my code! It will be really nice if you could share some of your thoughts on it! Thanks!

Comment: But why you want the argument to be Vertex** vertexarray? You need the argument to be an array of Vertex, right? You would need it to be Vertex **vertexarray if inside the function you would allocate memory that is accessed by *vertexarray. But it's not the case in your finalize

Comment: Sure, I understand that now! Thanks!